# Hide parameters from the URL for users to see

Tags: php

I was just wondering if there is any possible way of getting rid of the parameters in a link.
For example, I have this redirecting the user back to the original form if any errors come up:

```
www.mywebsite.com/form.php?error_code=1021
```

But I don't want the user to see the **error_code=1021**.

How would I code it in PHP so that after it redirect to the page with the error, it looks like this to the user:

```
www.mywebsite.com/form.php
```

Comment: Validate and output the errors without redirect.

Comment: Write the error code to a `$_SESSION` variable, redirect to `form.php` and have `form.php` check `$_SESSION` that as it loads.

Comment: Don't redirect, then. re-output the form with your error messages instead of redirecting.

Comment: This is a better way of doing what you require. Submit the form to the same PHP page `i.e. www.mywebsite.com/form.php`. Validate the inputs. If there are any errors, output the error. You don't need to store any error codes at all. If there aren't any errors process the input and redirect to the `success` page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the advice in the comments and not redirect, or if you must, I would use sessions:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['error_code'] = '1021';
header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/form.php');
exit;
```

Then in the form you would need `session_start()` and then access `$_SESSION['error_code']`.

Comment: @fastebro: what criterias did you use to determine it's "the best"?

Comment: @zerkms my personal work experience. Some php frameworks use this technique to display form errors.

Comment: @fastebro: it's subjective then

Comment: @fastebro: This solution is not thread safe and is prone to race conditions

Comment: Well, propose your solution for @Anuj Hari request.

Comment: @zermks i've read, PRG is a good design pattern for this situation.

Comment: @fastebro: it's not - you cannot persist the state between 2 requests easily. If the latest `GET` is stateful - then you have no choice other than to use the query string. Otherwise you're in stuck.

Comment: I never used this pattern, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @zerkms Thread safe + PHP is a good one! Let's hope the user won't fill 10 forms at the same time. :)

Comment: @CodeAngry: not only forms actually :-) The proposed `error_code` key is generic enough for the developer to use it somewhere else not only in forms validation :-)

Comment: @zerkms The error code name could be form + url specific. For a general-use solution. PS: I don't like SESSIONs eithers. I like cookies! :)

Comment: Yup sessions are always the way to go. Can't believe i didn't figure that out myself haha. Anyways thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Sessions are overkill in this case.

It's much more convenient just *not to redirect* after a form validation.

That's it - render the form and validate by the same script. That way it will also be trivial to re-fill the form with the previous values.

There is no practical reasons to follow the [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_cookie()` to set the error as a url-specific cookie and use `$_COOKIE['error_core']` when displaying the error to the user. Don't set an expiry date so the browser drops it on exit.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the examples on the session_start page from the php manual, you can find it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php